# Inheritance and prototypes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

We can create prototype for an object in JavaScript by assigning an object to the `Object.prototype` property.

```
function Animal() { };

Animal.prototype = {
  constructor: Animal,
  describe: function() {
    console.log("This is an animal");
  },
  eat: function() {
    console.log('Eating');
  }
};
```

And in the derived object (child object) if I want to add some more property to the object I can do this in the following way:

```
function Dog() {}
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;


Dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  console.log('barking');
}
Dog.prototype.guard = function() {
  console.log('guarding');
}
Dog.prototype.eat = function() {
  console.log('Dog is Eating');
}

let tipu = Object.create(Dog.prototype);
tipu.bark();
tipu.guard();
tipu.eat();
```

But what if I don't want to repeat `Dog.prototype` each time. I want to assign an object to the prototype property of child object (Elephant object below) like I did with the parent Animal ( `Animal.prototype = {...}` ).

```
function Elephant() { }
Elephant.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Elephant.prototype.constructor = Elephant;

Elephant.prototype = {
  play : function() {
    console.log("Playing in the jungle");
  },
  eat : function() {
    console.log("Elephant is eating");
  }
}

let hathi = new Elephant();
hathi.eat();
hathi.play();
```

Now when I do this it removes the describe() method of the parent from child.

```
hathi.describe();
```

This will throw error but `tipu.describe();` works just fine.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check the spelling of `Elephant` (`Element`)...

Comment: Let's talk about the `Elephant` in the room...

Answer (score 0):

> But what if I don't want to repeat `Dog.prototype` each time. I want to assign an object to the prototype

then do it.

```
function Dog() {}
Dog.prototype = Object.assign(
    Object.create(Animal.prototype),
    {
        constructor: Dog,

        bark(){
            console.log('barking');
        },

        guard(){
            console.log('guarding');
        },

        eat(){
            console.log('Dog is Eating');
        }
    }
);
```

Or you take a look in the brand new [class Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) that has been introduced 3 years ago.

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    bark(){
        console.log('barking');
    },

    guard(){
        console.log('guarding');
    },

    eat(){
        console.log('Dog is Eating');
    }
}
```